# JSON API with Flask - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, api, flask, server, json-api

I'm an absolute newbie on Flask and API things. I want to host my Json with API in localhost with FLASK. But it says

> 500 Internal Server Error.

At my first try to run this Flask, it give me this 500 Internal Server error. Then I go from Ubuntu to Windows to play a game and browsing (I try to explain it clearly). And I come back again to Ubuntu.

**And I'm doing the exactly same thing as I'm doing it in my first try which I got this 500 Internal
Server error. BUT I DON'T KNOW, this time it works. And I'm sure
that I don't do anything but just like my first try**

This is the code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps
import json


client = MongoClient()
db = client.dbCrawlTwint

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_statistic_year", methods = ['GET'])
def get_statistic_year():
        statisticYear = db.statisticYear.find()
        return dumps(statisticYear)

@app.route("/get_statistic_month", methods = ['GET'])
def get_statistic_month():
        statisticMonth = db.statisticMonth.find()
        return dumps(statisticMonth)

@app.route("/get_statistic_week", methods = ['GET'])
def get_statistic_week():
        statisticWeek = db.statisticWeek.find()
        return dumps(statisticWeek)

@app.route("/get_statistic_day", methods = ['GET'])
def get_statistic_day():
        statisticDay = db.statisticDay.find()
        return dumps(statisticDay)
```

And this is the error.log

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Aug/2019 13:21:13] "GET /get_statistic_month HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR:restAPI:Exception on /get_statistic_month [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/alramdein/Documents/Angular-exp/angular-statistic/flask/restAPI.py", line 21, in get_statistic_month
    return dumps(statisticMonth)
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/json_util.py", line 383, in dumps
    return json.dumps(_json_convert(obj, json_options), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/json_util.py", line 421, in _json_convert
    return list((_json_convert(v, json_options) for v in obj))
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/json_util.py", line 421, in <genexpr>
    return list((_json_convert(v, json_options) for v in obj))
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1225, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1140, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1010, in __send_message
    helpers._check_command_response(first)
  File "/home/alramdein/anaconda3/envs/eventenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: there are no users authenticated
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [01/Aug/2019 13:21:14] "GET /get_statistic_month HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

And this is the error[image: And this is the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm notice that there is a

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: there are no users authenticated

When I post this question

Just add this 
in Windows

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/')
```

or this in Linux

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@172.17.0.1:27017/')
```

I didn't delete this because other people might have the same problem with me